# Clang claims constexpr member of generic lambda argument is not constexpr

Tags: c++, c++17, variant, generic-lambda

I would like to write a generic lambda as a visitor for a variant. The members of this variant contain a constexpr member value, which I would like to use in the visitor. For example:

```
#include <variant>

template<int r>
struct S {
    constexpr static int this_r = r;
};

int f(std::variant<S<0>, S<1>, S<2> > v) {
    return std::visit([](auto const& arg) {
        if constexpr(arg.this_r == 0) { return 42; }
        else { return arg.this_r; }
    }, v);
}

int g() {
    std::variant<S<0>, S<1>, S<2> > x = S<2>();
    return f(x);
}
```

GCC is happy to compile this code starting from about [version 7.1](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/kCAU3X). Clang, on the other hand, complains that the `arg.this_r == 0` argument to the `if constexpr` is not constant, going back to [version 4.0.0](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/1L3mwc) but this is still present in the [current trunk](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/YjRp3i).

Who is in the right here and how could I avoid this issue (assuming that a simple `if` does not cut it because one of the two branches is not instantiable)?

Addendum: Passing `arg` as a value instead of a const lvalue reference, Clang [is happy](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/3iGtwG), but unfortunately this is not an option for me.

Comment: I think the lambda argument `arg` is not a `constexpr` here. I'm not sure though.

Comment: `arg` itself is certainly not constexpr, but its member `this_r` is. Once the type of `arg` is known, `arg.this_r` should be constexpr?

Comment: @Claudius no, because `arg.this_r` is a member access expression of a non-constexpr object. `std::remove_cvref_t<decltype(arg)>::this_r` is a constant expression because it doesn't use a member access expression.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Makes sense, thank you!

Comment: @JonathanWakely OTOH, if I pass `arg` by value, Clang sees through it and considers `arg.this_rank` a constant expression (cf. my addendum). Is there some freedom to whether a compiler can consider something a constant expression or is this a case of GCC and Clang being more lenient than required by the standard?

Comment: There's no freedom, I think GCC has a bug. When you pass it by reference you're referring to some non-constant object outside the function, which isn't a constant.

Comment: Hmm, after looking into it further, maybe Clang has a bug. MSVC, Intel and GCC all agree it's OK: https://godbolt.org/z/0RcsLC

Comment: @JonathanWakely I think this is a standard bug, i think it's technically ill-formed, but shouldn't be.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `this_r` is a static member you can always access it without dereferencing (non constexpr) reference to object instance to make clang or other compilers happy:

```
int f(std::variant<S<0>, S<1>, S<2> > v) {
    return std::visit([](auto const& arg) {
        if constexpr(::std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg)>::this_r == 0) { return 42; }
        else { return ::std::remove_reference_t<decltype(arg)>::this_r; }
    }, v);
}
```

[online compiler](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/mH-pdB)

Comment: It doesn't exactly win the award for prettiness, but it seems to work and makes sense given @JonathanWakely's explanation. Thank you!